# Semisimple monoidal category with duals

Tags: ct.category-theory, modules, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

We say that an abelian category is **semisimple** if every object is a semisimple object, which is to say, a direct sum of finitely many simple objects.

Let $({\cal C},\otimes,*)$  be a semisimple monoidal category with duals. If $V$ is a simple object in ${\cal C}$, then can $V \otimes V$ ever contain $V^*$ as a summand?

Comment: I would say that an abelian category is semisimple if every short exact sequence splits. So I would regard $\text{Vect}$, the abelian category of not-necessarily-finite-dimensional vector spaces, as semisimple. I would also say that an object is semisimple if it's a direct sum, not necessarily finite, of simples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can.
Example: $\mathcal{C} = Rep-S_3$, and $V$ the two dimensional irreducible representation.
Then $V\otimes V$ splits as the direct sum $V\oplus \mathbb{1}\oplus \chi$ where $\mathbb{1}$ is the trivial representation and $\chi$ is the sign representation. The dual of $V$ is $V$ itself, which is a direct summand of $V\otimes V$.

Comment: An even simpler example: $1 \otimes 1 \simeq 1$, and $1$ is self dual.